# Symfony- Error ocurred when I try to make an entity

Tags: php, symfony, entity

When I use: php bin/console make:entity to create a new db entity, I get the following error:

In DoctrineHelper.php line 180:
Class "Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver" does not exist

This is my composer.json:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.13",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.12",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.2",
        "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/options-resolver": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.4.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/package-versions-deprecated": true,
            "symfony/flex": true
        },
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.4.*"
        }
    }
}
```

This is my DoctrineHelper.php:

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony MakerBundle package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry as LegacyManagerRegistry;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\ClassMetadata as LegacyClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException as LegacyPersistenceMappingException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AttributeDriver;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException as ORMMappingException;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\NamingStrategy;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory;
use Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;
use Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriver;
use Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain;
use Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException as PersistenceMappingException;
use Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Util\ClassNameDetails;
use Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Util\PhpCompatUtil;

/**
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 * @author Ryan Weaver <ryan@knpuniversity.com>
 * @author Sadicov Vladimir <sadikoff@gmail.com>
 *
 * @internal
 */
final class DoctrineHelper
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $entityNamespace;
    private $phpCompatUtil;

    /**
     * @var ManagerRegistry
     */
    private $registry;

    /**
     * @var array|null
     */
    private $mappingDriversByPrefix;

    private $attributeMappingSupport;

    /**
     * @var ManagerRegistry|LegacyManagerRegistry
     */
    public function __construct(string $entityNamespace, PhpCompatUtil $phpCompatUtil, $registry = null, bool $attributeMappingSupport = false, array $annotatedPrefixes = null)
    {
        $this->entityNamespace = trim($entityNamespace, '\\');
        $this->phpCompatUtil = $phpCompatUtil;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->attributeMappingSupport = $attributeMappingSupport;
        $this->mappingDriversByPrefix = $annotatedPrefixes;
    }

    /**
     * @return LegacyManagerRegistry|ManagerRegistry
     */
    public function getRegistry()
    {
        // this should never happen: we will have checked for the
        // DoctrineBundle dependency before calling this
        if (null === $this->registry) {
            throw new \Exception('Somehow the doctrine service is missing. Is DoctrineBundle installed?');
        }

        return $this->registry;
    }

    private function isDoctrineInstalled(): bool
    {
        return null !== $this->registry;
    }

    public function getEntityNamespace(): string
    {
        return $this->entityNamespace;
    }

    public function doesClassUseDriver(string $className, string $driverClass): bool
    {
        try {
            /** @var EntityManagerInterface $em */
            $em = $this->getRegistry()->getManagerForClass($className);
        } catch (\ReflectionException $exception) {
            // this exception will be thrown by the registry if the class isn't created yet.
            // an example case is the "make:entity" command, which needs to know which driver is used for the class to determine
            // if the class should be generated with attributes or annotations. If this exception is thrown, we will check based on the
            // namespaces for the given $className and compare it with the doctrine configuration to get the correct MappingDriver.

            return $this->isInstanceOf($this->getMappingDriverForNamespace($className), $driverClass);
        }

        if (null === $em) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Cannot find the entity manager for class "%s"', $className));
        }

        if (null === $this->mappingDriversByPrefix) {
            // doctrine-bundle <= 2.2
            $metadataDriver = $em->getConfiguration()->getMetadataDriverImpl();

            if (!$this->isInstanceOf($metadataDriver, MappingDriverChain::class)) {
                return $this->isInstanceOf($metadataDriver, $driverClass);
            }

            foreach ($metadataDriver->getDrivers() as $namespace => $driver) {
                if (0 === strpos($className, $namespace)) {
                    return $this->isInstanceOf($driver, $driverClass);
                }
            }

            return $this->isInstanceOf($metadataDriver->getDefaultDriver(), $driverClass);
        }

        $managerName = array_search($em, $this->getRegistry()->getManagers(), true);

        foreach ($this->mappingDriversByPrefix[$managerName] as [$prefix, $prefixDriver]) {
            if (0 === strpos($className, $prefix)) {
                return $this->isInstanceOf($prefixDriver, $driverClass);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function isClassAnnotated(string $className): bool
    {
        return $this->doesClassUseDriver($className, AnnotationDriver::class);
    }

    public function doesClassUsesAttributes(string $className): bool
    {
        return $this->doesClassUseDriver($className, AttributeDriver::class);
    }

    public function isDoctrineSupportingAttributes(): bool
    {
        return $this->isDoctrineInstalled() && $this->attributeMappingSupport && $this->phpCompatUtil->canUseAttributes();
    }

    public function getEntitiesForAutocomplete(): array
    {
        $entities = [];

        if ($this->isDoctrineInstalled()) {
            $allMetadata = $this->getMetadata();

            foreach (array_keys($allMetadata) as $classname) {
                $entityClassDetails = new ClassNameDetails($classname, $this->entityNamespace);
                $entities[] = $entityClassDetails->getRelativeName();
            }
        }

        sort($entities);

        return $entities;
    }

    /**
     * @return array|ClassMetadata|LegacyClassMetadata
     */
    public function getMetadata(string $classOrNamespace = null, bool $disconnected = false)
    {
        $classNames = (new \ReflectionClass(AnnotationDriver::class))->getProperty('classNames');
        $classNames->setAccessible(true);

        // Invalidating the cached AnnotationDriver::$classNames to find new Entity classes
        foreach ($this->mappingDriversByPrefix ?? [] as $managerName => $prefixes) {
            foreach ($prefixes as [$prefix, $annotationDriver]) {
                if (null !== $annotationDriver) {
                    $classNames->setValue($annotationDriver, null);
                }
            }
        }

        $metadata = [];

        /** @var EntityManagerInterface $em */
        foreach ($this->getRegistry()->getManagers() as $em) {
            $cmf = $em->getMetadataFactory();

            if ($disconnected) {
                try {
                    $loaded = $cmf->getAllMetadata();
                } catch (ORMMappingException $e) {
                    $loaded = $this->isInstanceOf($cmf, AbstractClassMetadataFactory::class) ? $cmf->getLoadedMetadata() : [];
                } catch (LegacyPersistenceMappingException $e) {
                    $loaded = $this->isInstanceOf($cmf, AbstractClassMetadataFactory::class) ? $cmf->getLoadedMetadata() : [];
                } catch (PersistenceMappingException $e) {
                    $loaded = $this->isInstanceOf($cmf, AbstractClassMetadataFactory::class) ? $cmf->getLoadedMetadata() : [];
                }

                $cmf = new DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory();
                $cmf->setEntityManager($em);

                foreach ($loaded as $m) {
                    $cmf->setMetadataFor($m->getName(), $m);
                }

                if (null === $this->mappingDriversByPrefix) {
                    // Invalidating the cached AnnotationDriver::$classNames to find new Entity classes
                    $metadataDriver = $em->getConfiguration()->getMetadataDriverImpl();
                    if ($this->isInstanceOf($metadataDriver, MappingDriverChain::class)) {
                        foreach ($metadataDriver->getDrivers() as $driver) {
                            if ($this->isInstanceOf($driver, AnnotationDriver::class)) {
                                $classNames->setValue($driver, null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach ($cmf->getAllMetadata() as $m) {
                if (null === $classOrNamespace) {
                    $metadata[$m->getName()] = $m;
                } else {
                    if ($m->getName() === $classOrNamespace) {
                        return $m;
                    }

                    if (0 === strpos($m->getName(), $classOrNamespace)) {
                        $metadata[$m->getName()] = $m;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $metadata;
    }

    public function createDoctrineDetails(string $entityClassName): ?EntityDetails
    {
        $metadata = $this->getMetadata($entityClassName);

        if ($this->isInstanceOf($metadata, ClassMetadata::class)) {
            return new EntityDetails($metadata);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public function isClassAMappedEntity(string $className): bool
    {
        if (!$this->isDoctrineInstalled()) {
            return false;
        }

        return (bool) $this->getMetadata($className);
    }

    private function isInstanceOf($object, string $class): bool
    {
        if (!\is_object($object)) {
            return false;
        }

        $legacyClass = str_replace('Doctrine\\Persistence\\', 'Doctrine\\Common\\Persistence\\', $class);

        return $object instanceof $class || $object instanceof $legacyClass;
    }

    public function getPotentialTableName(string $className): string
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getRegistry()->getManager();

        if (!$entityManager instanceof EntityManagerInterface) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('ObjectManager is not an EntityManagerInterface.');
        }

        /** @var NamingStrategy $namingStrategy */
        $namingStrategy = $entityManager->getConfiguration()->getNamingStrategy();

        return $namingStrategy->classToTableName($className);
    }

    public function isKeyword(string $name): bool
    {
        /** @var Connection $connection */
        $connection = $this->getRegistry()->getConnection();

        return $connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getReservedKeywordsList()->isKeyword($name);
    }

    /**
     * this method tries to find the correct MappingDriver for the given namespace/class
     * To determine which MappingDriver belongs to the class we check the prefixes configured in Doctrine and use the
     * prefix that has the closest match to the given $namespace.
     *
     * this helper function is needed to create entities with the configuration of doctrine if they are not yet been registered
     * in the ManagerRegistry
     */
    private function getMappingDriverForNamespace(string $namespace): ?MappingDriver
    {
        $lowestCharacterDiff = null;
        $foundDriver = null;

        foreach ($this->mappingDriversByPrefix ?? [] as $mappings) {
            foreach ($mappings as [$prefix, $driver]) {
                $diff = substr_compare($namespace, $prefix, 0);

                if ($diff >= 0 && (null === $lowestCharacterDiff || $diff < $lowestCharacterDiff)) {
                    $lowestCharacterDiff = $diff;
                    $foundDriver = $driver;
                }
            }
        }

        return $foundDriver;
    }
}
```

Line 180 is:

```
$classNames = (new \ReflectionClass(AnnotationDriver::class))->getProperty('classNames');
```

What could be the problem? I tried a lot of things but I'am not capable of solve it

Comment: Is it possible you have Symfony using an optimized autoloader that you need to clear? https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/performance.html#optimize-composer-autoloader

Comment: Hey Chris, I did what you told me: I've done a composer dump-autoload --no-dev --classmap-authoritative and then I tried to php bin/console make:entity again, but it appears another error now: uncaught error: Class "Symfony \Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle" not found :(

Comment: @ChrisHaas do you know another idea to solve it?

Comment: I have reinstalled doctrine with composer require symfony/orm-pack. I have noticed that it installed OK but then the files inside it (like the same AnnotationDriver) have compile errors.

Comment: If you are doing composer dump-autoload ... --no-dev, then you are leaving out the development bundles. On this case you need make composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 3):

This work for me.

Composer.json - change:
and
composer.lock- delete

```
"doctrine/orm": "^2.12",
```

to:

```
"doctrine/orm": "^2.11",
```

add (to prevent 2.12 being installed):

```
"conflict": {
  "symfony/symfony": "*",
  "doctrine/orm": "2.12.0"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a `composer update` works for me.

If not, try install `"symfony/maker-bundle": "1.33.*"`

then run `composer update`

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the file  composer.json by changing the orm version to 2.5 and then update your project dependencies .

"doctrine/orm": "^2.5"

`composer update`

[Composer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjPzZ.png)